# Не применяются свои стили для элементов активности

Tags: android, android-style, androidx

Перевел приложение на AndroidX. В связи с чем пришлось все темы активностей перевести на AppCompat. Но выявилась проблема, что, например, все кнопки стали отображаться обычным серым прямоугольником, хотя раньше к ним был применен свой стиль. Никак не могу понять в чем проблема. При чем некоторые элементы, например, CheckBox остался без изменений, т.е. в своем (переопределенном) стиле.

```java
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSettingsOsn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txtSettingsOsn"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_settings_bar"
                style="@style/txtSettings"/>
```

Такое ощущение, что *style* переваривает не все. Позиция `android:background="@drawable/bg_settings_bar"` уже есть в *style*, но не применяется, а если ее вынести оттуда, то стиль применяется.

Comment: Кнопку устанавливали как  com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton ? стиль кнопки унаследован от Widget.MaterialComponents.Button ?

Comment: @Романыч, да обычная кнопка <Button> с Palette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как всегда, сначала задаешь вопрос, а потом сам же на него и отвечаешь.
Оказалось, что проблема была только в `background`, а именно в *style* было написано так:

```java
        <item name="background">@drawable/fancybtn_green</item>
```

а надо так:

```java
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/fancybtn_green</item>
```

Хотя раньше работало. Наверное это из-за AndroidX

Comment: Как всегда , задаешь вопрос по Button а в пример выкладываешь  TextView, Как всегда задаешь вопрос про стили а в пример выкладываешь XML разметку layout файла, как всегда ждешь сутки ответа, а потом за 3 минуты гуглишь)))))))